# Where is the editor choice kept in ranger?

Tags: ubuntu, alternatives, ranger, ed

On a fresh `ranger` install I tried to open `neofetch` config with `ranger` and selected `ed` to see what is it. I am glad <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> worked to exit the `ed`, but now `ranger` opens all files with it. Restarting terminal didn't work. `~/.config/ranger` is empty:

```
$ ls -la .config/ranger/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 techtonik techtonik 4096 ліс 24 23:32 .
drwx------ 24 techtonik techtonik 4096 ліс 24 22:19 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 techtonik techtonik   35 ліс 24 23:32 bookmarks
-rw-r--r--  1 techtonik techtonik    0 ліс 24 23:32 history
-rw-r--r--  1 techtonik techtonik    0 ліс  7 14:03 tagged
```

How to fix that?

**UPD**: `$EDITOR` is empty, `rifle` still runs the `ed`.

```
$ rifle -l ~/.config/neofetch/config.conf 
0:editor::$EDITOR -- "$@"
1:pager::"$PAGER" -- "$@"
$ echo $EDITOR

$ rifle ~/.config/neofetch/config.conf 
13949
```

**UPD2**: Ubuntu 18.10

**UPD3**: I don't see that `ed` is selected by OS

```
$ update-alternatives --display editor
editor - auto mode
  link best version is /bin/nano
  link currently points to /bin/nano
  link editor is /usr/bin/editor
  slave editor.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/editor.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz is /usr/share/man/fr/man1/editor.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz is /usr/share/man/it/man1/editor.1.gz
  slave editor.ja.1.gz is /usr/share/man/ja/man1/editor.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz is /usr/share/man/pl/man1/editor.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz is /usr/share/man/ru/man1/editor.1.gz
/bin/ed - priority -100
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ed.1.gz
/bin/nano - priority 40
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/nano.1.gz
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz: /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ja.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ja/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
/usr/bin/vim.tiny - priority 15
  slave editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.fr.1.gz: /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.it.1.gz: /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ja.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ja/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.pl.1.gz: /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
  slave editor.ru.1.gz: /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
```

Comment: [Ed, man! !man ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html)

Comment: Did you try running it as e.g. `EDITOR=vim ranger`?

Comment: Oh, I am sure it will invoke `vim` as expected. However, I want to know where `ranger` stores the `ed` setting.

Comment: It is an enviromental VAR set in the OS/SHELL/WHATEVER other than in ranger itself. global

Comment: @dessert You know your stuff too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1385#issuecomment-441444916) by @toon in `ranger` tracker, `ranger` doesn't provide any editor selection dialogs if EDITOR is not set. It resorts to hardcoded `vim`, but Debian/Ubuntu hackers [patch ranger](https://sources.debian.org/patches/ranger/1.7.1-1/0002-make-sensible-decisions-on-which-pager-and-editor.patch/) to use `sensible-editor`, which is a bash script that is not connected with `updates-alternatives` in any way, and stores editor choice in `~/.selected_editor`:

```
$ cat ~/.selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/ed"
```

I guess this `sensible-editor` bash script was implemented as a hack, because `update-alternatives` works on a system level, and users without root needed to edit bash config to select their EDITOR (which doesn't work for everyone).

Instead of implicitly patching `ranger`, the Debian folks could explicitly set `EDITOR=sensible-editor` for user level sessions. "Explicit is better than implicit". At least this way we won't spend so much time here. Digging `man` I found that `sensible-editor` is explained in [this policy page](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#editors-and-pagers):

> If it is very hard to adapt a program to make use of the EDITOR or PAGER variables, that program may be configured to use /usr/bin/sensible-editor and /usr/bin/sensible-pager as the editor or pager program respectively.

And according to this text, `ranger` should not be patched, because it is already aware and makes use of EDITOR.

---

Closing this with final rants, why the `ed` is given as the user-level choice of Linux editor in 2018 ???..

Answer (score 0):

Check what editor, the os itself is pointing at. I think, ranger is looking at the now default for the os. Change the os's perfered editor, and I think it will change rangers.

sudo update-alternatives --config editor

Type the number of the one you want and hit enter.

In your case

> auto mode

```
/bin/ed - priority -100
```

Each alternative has a priority associated with it. When a link group is in automatic mode, the alternatives pointed to by members of the group will be those which have the highest priority.

Set priority to 10

Change that and you should be good.

Comment: I updated the question that I am using Ubuntu 18.10. I have no idea how to check what editor Ubuntu is pointing at.

Comment: Updated the question to show that `ed` is probably not selected as default OS editor by `update-alternatives`.

Comment: /bin/ed - priority -100

Comment: `-100` means it should be selected last, after `nano` (40) and `vim` (30). If I run `editor ~/.config/neofetch/config.conf` the `nano` is opened.

Comment: Ok, humor me and change it to 10. Tell me what happens.

Comment: I am not sure I want to humor you. =/

Comment: It's ok, I am good with that, I still know what I know. You know!